# What does it mean that the modification order is not a total order?

Tags: c, atomic

> Each atomic object has its own associated modification order, ***which is a total order*** of modifications made to that object. If, from some thread's point of view, modification A of some atomic M happens-before modification B of the same atomic M, then in the modification order of M, A occurs before B.
>
> Note that although each atomic object has its own modification order, ***it is not a total order***; different threads may observe modifications to different atomic objects in different orders.

Aren't the two bold statements contradictory? I found them on https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic and was wondering what exactly is going on now - is it a total order or not? And what exactly is guaranteed now and what isn't?

Comment: _Aren't the two bold statements contradictory?_ I don't think so. The first statement is about an order for a single object. The second is about different objects. Simple example: If one thread writes `a=1` and then `a=2`, another threads cannot observe `a` being 2 first and 1 second. But if one thread writes `a=1` and then `b=2`, another threads may observe `b` being 2 before `a` being 1 (e.g., with relaxed atomics and assuming `a` and `b` initialized to 0).

Comment: I come to the same conclusion. The total order relates to modifications to **that** object. But globally the modifications are not totally ordered regarding **different** objects.

Comment: Alright, I see! So the order of changes for one object is the same for every thread, but the order in which different objects are changed isn't. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bad choice of words by cppreference. The important sentence is in fact the last sentence: **different threads may observe modifications to different atomic objects in different orders**

So if atomic object 1 has the totally ordered sequence of modifications A B C, and atomic object 2 has the totally ordered sequence D E F, then all threads will see A before C and D before F, but threads may disagree whether A comes before D. Therefore, the set of all modifications `{A B D C E F}` has no total order.

But all threads that agree that B comes before E will also agree that A comes before F. Partial orders still give some guarantees.